# How to transform data before loading into BigQuery in Apache Airflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I am new to Apache Airflow. My task is to read data from Google Cloud Storage, transform the data and upload the transformed data into BigQuery table. I'm able to get data from Cloud Storage bucket and directly store that to BigQuery table. I'm not sure how to include the transform function in this pipeline.

Here's my code:

```
# Import libraries needed for the operation
import airflow
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator

# Default Argument
default_args = {
    'owner': <OWNER_NAME>,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
}

# DAG Definition
dag = DAG('load_from_bucket_to_bq',
schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
default_args=default_args)

# Variable Configurations
BQ_CONN_ID = <CONN_ID>
BQ_PROJECT = <PROJECT_ID>
BQ_DATASET = <DATASET_ID>

with dag:
    # Tasks
    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start'
    )

    upload = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='load_from_bucket_to_bigquery',
        bucket=<BUCKET_NAME>,
        source_objects=['*.csv'],
        schema_fields=[
            {'name': 'Active_Cases', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            {'name': 'Country', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            {'name': 'Last_Update', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            {'name': 'New_Cases', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            {'name': 'New_Deaths', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            {'name': 'Total_Cases', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            {'name': 'Total_Deaths', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
            {'name': 'Total_Recovered', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        ],
        destination_project_dataset_table=BQ_PROJECT + '.' + BQ_DATASET + '.' + <TABLE_NAME>,
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=BQ_CONN_ID,
        bigquery_conn_id=BQ_CONN_ID,
        dag = dag
    )

    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end'
    )

    # Setting Dependencies
    start >> upload >> end
```

Any help on how to proceed is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of transform will you be doing?

Comment: I get COVID cases data for every day. I want to do a difference of cases for each day and store that in BigQuery table.

Comment: You can try creating a python function that does the transform and use [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#) on your DAG to call the function at runtime.

Comment: Is there an operator to get data from Cloud Storage Bucket and use that in a Python function? I couldn't find it, that's why I directly used the GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator.

Comment: Is GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator the only operator to download the data from GCP bucket?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the conversation with @sachinmb27 as an answer. The transform can be placed in a python function and use [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#) to call the transform function at runtime. More details on what operators can be used in Airflow can be seen in [Airflow Operator docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html).